# How to use simple html sentence and mustache object on same line

Tags: inline, mustache, html-rendering

I am using mustache templating for creating a webpage .I am filling data into a table as

```
<table style="width:765px;border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 5px">
<tr>
 <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">a) <span  style="Display:Inline-Block">{{{[0].choice}}}</span></td>
 <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">b) <span style="Display:Inline-Block">{{{[1].choice}}}</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">c) <span style="Display:Inline-Block">{{{[2].choice}}}</span></td>
    <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">d) <span style="Display:Inline-Block">{{{[3].choice}}}</span></td>
</tr></table>
```

My problem is that when the size of data in mustache object is more than 40 character than the whole thing goes in next line like

> a)
>
> Hello Here I am Writing Big Text To Experiment It's performance on
>   Higher Number of Characters

But i want it like

> a) Hello Here I am Writing Big Text To Experiment It's performance on
>   Higher Number of Characters

so i want to know is there any way of getting what i want on making changes on front-end only or i have to add options in database.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here is the behaviour of an `inline-block` element under circumstances when its content is too long for the space left on the current line - it breaks to the next one.

To get the behaviour you're looking for, you want to use an `inline` element instead. In other words, leaving the `<span>` unstyled should be enough; it is by default an `inline` element:

```
<table style="width:765px;border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 5px">
<tr>
 <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">a) <span>{{{[0].choice}}}</span></td>
 <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">b) <span>{{{[1].choice}}}</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">c) <span>{{{[2].choice}}}</span></td>
    <td VALIGN=top ALIGN=left style="width:380px">d) <span>{{{[3].choice}}}</span></td>
</tr></table>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ys337Lns/) to demonstrate a comparison of using inline/inline block in this scenario. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: yes i tried this but no improvement. and also i want to tell that the data coming from mustache is html type i.e. <p>Hello Here I am Writing Big Text To Experiment It's performance on Higher Number of Characters</p> that i think also a problem

Comment: All right, that detail would definitely also contribute to the problem. Though make sure you remove both the `<p>` tags and `inline-block`, otherwise my point about `inline-block` behaviour still stands.

Answer (score 0):

In this Case The Problem Is that The Data coming in mustache is of HTML type i.e. of the form `<p> Hello Here I am Writing Big Text To Experiment It's performance on Higher Number of Characters</p>` and because of this a new line is coming . so i just removed these p tags from another page which stores the data in database.and now it's coming fine.